# Else is hitting every time

Tags: javascript

I build this type of Code

```
countdown();
function countdown() {
    var zaehler = 1;
    while (zaehler <= 5) {
        document.getElementById("ueberschrift" + zaehler).style.display = "none";
        zaehler++;
        if (zaehler < 5) {
            document.getElementById("ueberschrift" + zaehler).style.display = "inline";
            window.setTimeout('countdown()', 5000);
        } else {
            document.getElementById("ueberschrift1").style.display = "inline";
            window.setTimeout('countdown()', 5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly everytime the else is true and is done. But the first 4 times on the while loop the `zaehler` variable isn't bigger than 5 or am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) When asking other people for help, please take the time to format and indent your code in a readable way. (It's a good idea when *not* asking for help, too.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a `while` loop, you want a chained series of `setTimeout` calls. Keep the `zaehler` variable outside the function, so that its value persists from call to call.

Separately, don't pass strings into `setTimeout`. Just pass a reference to the function. And since this is a countdown, I assume you don't want to keep going once `zaehler` has reached 5, so you want to remove that `setTimeout` in the `else` branch.

Finally, since you're continuing

```
var zaehler = 1;
countdown();
function countdown() {
    document.getElementById("ueberschrift" + zaehler).style.display = "none";
    zaehler++;
    if (zaehler < 5) {
        document.getElementById("ueberschrift" + zaehler).style.display = "inline";
        window.setTimeout(countdown, 5000);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ueberschrift1").style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

---

Side note: There's nothing really gained by using `window.setTimeout` instead of `setTimeout`. `setTimeout` and `window` are both globals, both resolved the same way. `window.setTimeout` just means that the JavaScript engine first has to resolve the `window` variable (which it does by eventually finding it on the global object) and then look up `setTimeout` on the global object. Whereas just `setTimeout` only does the first part of that, avoiding the need for the second. But if you prefer it as a matter of style, of course, that's fine; this code isn't going to be impacted by the ever-so-tiny amount of extra work. :-)